# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException in jsp in spring web app even though property is present

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and am bit lost on the error of javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException which I am currently getting in my first test app.
I am trying to display a list of persons and then on press of a button taking to a new page which asks for the new entry of person details.

So I got Person model as

```
    public class Person {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;


public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

    }
```

The method addPersonInitial gets called whenever user asks for new entry of a person.Thereafter when user fills the form the submit is handled by the function addPersonFinal. The function should add the new entry and redirect back the page which shows the list of persons already there.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="person")
    public class PersonController{

@Autowired
private PersonService personservice;

@RequestMapping(value="viewAll", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewAll() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("viewAll");
    mav.addObject("persons", personservice.getAllPersons());
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="addPersonInitial", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addPersonInitial() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("addPersonInitial");
    mav.addObject("person", new Person());
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="addPersonFinal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addPersonFinal(@ModelAttribute(value="person") Person person) {
    this.personservice.addPerson(person);
    return this.viewAll();
}

    }
```

The code in jsp is

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Add Person Initial</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <table>
<tbody>
<form:form method="POST" action="addPersonFinal" commandName="person">
    <tr>
    <td><label for="firstName">First Name: </label><form:input path= "firstName" /> </td>
    <td><label for="lastName">Last Name: </label><form:input path="lastName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add" /></td>
    </tr>
</form:form>
</tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When user submits the form data for a new user I get the following error

type Exception report

message javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'FirstName' not found on type net.viralpatel.spring3.model.Person

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'FirstName' not found on type net.viralpatel.spring3.model.Person
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Everything looks okay...try to clean and build the project. Make sure you have a fresh build on the server when you run it.

Comment: May you provide the brief project structure ?